# How to locked token in chain?

Tags: parachain, token

I want to locked token, how can we do this?

[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way:

```rs
// pallet_x/src/lib.rs
pub trait Config {
  Currency: frame_support::traits::LockableCurrency;
}

fn lock<T: Config>() {
  T::Currency::set_lock(..);
}
```

And if you make the `lock` as an extrinsic. Then user could call this call to lock their token. (Just an example, you can make more complex logic base on this)